# Black Screen After Upgrading To 16.04

Tags: tty

I need some help with a slight problem.  I just upgraded to Ubuntu 16.04 but when it finished installing and when I rebooted the computer a black screen appears saying tty1 and it says to login but when I do it looks like a terminal. So I was wondering if any of you can help me with what I have to so I can use 16.04 normally.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like it might be a video driver issue. Can you login to the terminal and type

> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
>
> sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-intel
>
> sudo apt-get install mesa-utils

and see if that helps, if not we can try something else!